# jsonPath query for single array object not working

Tags: json, scala, gatling, jsonpath

I have a JSON look like this and if I make a query
`jsonPath($.book[?(@.price)]).is("8.95")` it works.

```
{"book": [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      } 
       ]
}
```

But, if I have a JSON with only one object inside it, the same query logic won't work. i.e `jsonPath($.book[?(@.price)]).is("8.95")`

Any thoughts why ?

```
  {"book": [ 
          { "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
          }
        ]}
```

I need to stick with query as I'm not sure whether the API will return multiple object or single one.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found that's Gatling's bug, it is not able to parse the jsonPath with query having some braces e.g. `{ or [ or )`

https://github.com/gatling/jsonpath/issues/23